# Limit of $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{x} \right)$ as $x$ approaches $0$ does not exist, with squeeze theorem

Tags: limits

I understand that $\frac{\pi}{0}$ would be infinity, hence $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{x} \right)$ does not have a limit as $x$ approach $0$.

But if I would to use the squeeze theorem:
$$-1 \leq \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{x} \right) \leq 1$$
shouldn't it be zero? Or does the squeeze theorem not work here?

Comment: The squeeze theorem needs the limits on the l.h.s and the r.h.s to be equal to the limit squeezed between them, which is not the case here.

Comment: oh, right i misinterpreted it thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just because it is bounded doesn't mean it has a limit. For example, I can construct a sequence: $$-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,\dots$$

and for this sequence, it is true that $-2\leq a_n \leq 2$. That only proves that the sequence is *bounded*, not that it converges.

In order for the squeeze theorem to work, the left and right sides of the inequality need to converge. For example, if $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and $x\to\infty$, then you could say $$-\frac 1x<f(x)<\frac1x,$$

and because $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1x=\lim_{x\to\infty}-\frac1x=0$$

the limit of $f$ is also $0$.

You don't have that. You only know that $-1\leq f(x)\leq 1$ which is not enough to use the squeeze theorem.

---

That said, another huge warning:

Your argument, saying

> $\pi/0$ would be infinity, hence $\sin(\pi/x)$ does not have a limit as $x\to0$

is completely inadequate. There are several functions $f$ for which $\lim_{x\to 0} f(\frac{x}{\pi})$ exists, even though, as you say, "$\frac\pi0$ would be infinity". For example, take $f(y) = e^{-|y|}$. Then the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(\frac\pi x) = \lim_{x\to 0}e^{-\frac{\pi}{|x|}}$$
exists and is equal to $0$.